# ¿Cómo agregar texto dentro de un grid?

Tags: html, css, diseño, frontend, bootstrap-5

Lo que planteo es cómo añadir un texto con la etiqueta `<p>` para que quede dentro del `Grid` de cada caja. Ya que necesito poner debajo de la imagen la descripción del programa.

Cuando añado el texto, este se separa por líneas muy extensas y no se queda dentro de la caja.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.caja {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid #ee2b7b;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <h3>Asistente en Diseño Grafico</h3>
  <img src="/IMG/diseñografico.png" height="auto" width="auto">
</div>
<div class="caja">
  <h3>Soporte de Sistemas Informaticos</h3>
  <img src="/IMG/soporteinformatico.png" height="auto" width="auto">
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes colocar todo el código para replicarlo en un Fiddle?

Comment: Hola Juan David, bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar una imagen de lo que quieres obtener?, de paso te invito a que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Si la respuesta ofrece una solución a tu pregunta, te invito a marcarla como útil con el check al lado izquierdo y darle un voto positivo. así ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad y la respuesta servirá de referencia para futuros visitantes. Si no fue útil o te quedan dudas, puedes dejar un comentario debajo de ella y buscamos otra solución o te aclaramos las dudas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los elementos que están dentro de un contenedor heredan los estilos del contenedor como tal.

El problema que tienes está en la propiedad `line-height: 150px;` que está al final de `caja`. *La dejé comentada para que realices los ajustes tal como los necesites en tu proyecto.*

Con esta propiedad le estás dando un espaciado vertical excesivamente amplio a cada elemento y a su vez, a cada línea del párrafo.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.caja {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid #ee2b7b;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /*line-height: 150px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <h3>Asistente en Diseño Grafico</h3>
  <img src="/IMG/diseñografico.png" height="auto" width="auto">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum a ornare neque, vel tempus lectus. Mauris feugiat ex bibendum mauris placerat auctor. Vivamus ultrices ante a ligula tempus, eu laoreet sapien efficitur. Mauris eleifend, massa eu sodales
    facilisis, massa ex suscipit metus, vel vulputate justo urna accumsan ipsum. Aenean placerat odio ut accumsan aliquam. Aliquam varius iaculis mi, quis scelerisque leo rutrum ac. Duis rutrum facilisis imperdiet. Quisque sed lobortis odio, ut auctor
    diam. Etiam congue vestibulum mi ac blandit. Donec ac dolor ac dolor porttitor condimentum vel et odio. Aenean elit dolor, tincidunt sed volutpat vel, porta vel ante.</p>
</div>
<div class="caja">
  <h3>Soporte de Sistemas Informaticos</h3>
  <img src="/IMG/soporteinformatico.png" height="auto" width="auto">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum a ornare neque, vel tempus lectus. Mauris feugiat ex bibendum mauris placerat auctor. Vivamus ultrices ante a ligula tempus, eu laoreet sapien efficitur. Mauris eleifend, massa eu sodales
    facilisis, massa ex suscipit metus, vel vulputate justo urna accumsan ipsum. Aenean placerat odio ut accumsan aliquam. Aliquam varius iaculis mi, quis scelerisque leo rutrum ac. Duis rutrum facilisis imperdiet. Quisque sed lobortis odio, ut auctor
    diam. Etiam congue vestibulum mi ac blandit. Donec ac dolor ac dolor porttitor condimentum vel et odio. Aenean elit dolor, tincidunt sed volutpat vel, porta vel ante.</p>
</div>
```